# FK from model to external FK from another model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have model **"Cities"** in **"external_app"** app like this:

```
class Cities(models.Model):
CityName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, db_index=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

I have second app, **"Address_program"** with few models:

```
class CityRegions(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('external_app.Cities', default=0, verbose_name=' City', related_name='City_for_region')
    city_region = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default='', verbose_name='City region', unique=True)
    city_region_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='City region slug')
```

and second model for sub-regions in region. Now I want to publish used cities in CityRegions model. I try to add FK for city field

```
class RegionSquares(models.Model):
city = models.ForeignKey(CityRegions, default=0, verbose_name='City', related_name='City_for_regionsquare', to_field='city')
region = models.ForeignKey(CityRegions, default=0, verbose_name='City region',related_name='Region')
    region_square = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default='', verbose_name='City sub-region')
    region_square_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='City sub-region slug')
```

when I try to make migrations I get error with message **"(fields.E311) 'CityRegions.city' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key".**

When I set unique=True in CityRegions.City field and try to migrate I get error with message: "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed..."

Question is how to publish list of used in **CityRegions** model cities in **RegionSquares** model?

In common app should have few models: 
 - editanle lists of city regions with current city (region and city should be show)
 - editable sub-reqions list for every city region (city, region and sub-region should be show)
 - editable list of streets (city, region and sub-region should be shown)

Scheme:

```
**cities** (model. Used in another apps of the project)
  |-->**citie's regions** (parent for sub-regions) (city and region should me show in admin)
      |--> **region's sub-regions** (parent for streets) (city,region and sub-region should me show in admin)
          |--> **list of streets** (city,region, sub-region and street should me show in admin)
```

Sample data:

```
**Cities:** Moscow, Novosibirsk, Kemerovo
**Regions (city is parent):** Moscow - SVAO, Moscow - TSAO, Novosibirsk - Centralnij, Kemerovo - Jugniy
**Sub regions (City and region are parents):** Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A; Moscow - SVAO - subregion B; Moscow - SVAO sub-region C. Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region A. Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region B
**Streets (City, region and sub-region are parents):** Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street A; Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street B; Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street C; Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region B -s treet A; Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region B street B... and so on
```

Desired result:

```
Moscow
   Moscow - SVAO
     Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street A
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street B
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region A - street C
     Moscow - SVAO - sub-region B
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region B - street A
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region B - street B
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region B - street C
     Moscow - SVAO - sub-region C
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region C - street A
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region C - street B
         Moscow - SVAO - sub-region C - street C
Novosibirsk
   Novosibirsk - Centralnij
     Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region A - street A
     Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region A - street B
     Novosibirsk - Centralnij - sub-region A - street C

and so on...
```

I using **Django 1.11** and python 2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failed migration could be that you have multiple `CityRegions` with same `city`

Answer (score 0):

`city` is not the PK (primary key) of CityRegions, so you should not refer it. Uniqueness fails because there are already repetative values - which is fine.

To make it work:

a) normalize your data model and remove `city` field from `RegionSquares` - achieve it via `region` when needed. Like `CityRegions.objects.filter(region__city__CityName='Moscow')`

or

b) reference `City` model itself:

```
class RegionSquares(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('external_app.Cities', default=0, verbose_name=' City', related_name='City_for_region')
    ...
```

equally to `CityRegions` definition of this field.

## upd

Again, if you question is still about *how to model* demonstrated relations (and get rid of all the errors mentioned in your question), then the answer is already here - remove `city` field from `RegionSquares` model. You already have there link to `region` which (the region record) contains `city` value. This is option `a` described above.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know about how to output cities in view model. But I should show used cities in Django admin in CityRegions model

Comment: Do you want to have a list within single record's field?

Comment: What do you mean? By the way, you can write Russian.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired result to your question. ps this website is for english only.

Comment: Sample data and some explanations are added.

Comment: Please add desired result. What does `list of used in CityRegions model cities in RegionSquares` mean, what would it be for given sample data.

Comment: Yes, please. Added.